# Fill Dropdown Based on Another's Selection with a Variable/Function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-select, forms

I have two drop down lists generated from SQL queries on a database. They are the following:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'Rosters') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT City, Name FROM Teams");

echo "<select name='Teams'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($city, $team);
              $city = $row['City'];
              $name = $row['Name'];
              $fullname = $city." ".$name;
              echo '<option value="'.$fullname.'">'.$fullname.'</option>';

 }

echo "</select>";
?>
```

and

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'Rosters') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$team = "Chicago Blackhawks";

$result = $conn->query("SELECT Number, First, Last FROM `$team`");

echo "<select name='Players'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($number, $first, $last);
              $number = $row['Number'];
              $first = $row['First'];
              $last = $row['Last'];
              $fullname = $first." ".$last;
              echo '<option value="'.$fullname.'">'.$number." - ".$fullname.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";
?>
```

The first one has is a list of teams in the NHL. The second one is a list of players from that team. I am trying to make it so that the second one will update when the first one is changed (based on the "value" of the "option"). For this to work, the $team variable in the second snippet of code need to be updated. Since PHP is server-side and cannot be dynamically updated, how would I do this? Even with AJAX the answer doesn't seem obvious. Am i using a flawed approach altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax on change of first dropdown and call php file from ajax and return data from php file to ajax and display it in second dropdown.

Comment: The problem is that both should be displayed on launch, and it should update every time the selection is changed. I need to refresh that portion of the code (the second PHP snippet), but I'm not sure how to do that and to be honest AJAX scares me as a beginner to this kind of programming...

Answer (score 0):

First, write a onchange event handler, it use ajax to send the "team" option to server side, then write a php to receive the "team" option from client side, which retrieve the player information from DB,after that reformat the data in XML or json format,send to client side.

Finally, write a javascript function to parse the server side response and update the web page.

This is the logical flow for solving your problem. You may go to google to search the above keyword for sample code.

Here is an simple sample code:
HTML file content:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP/Ajax update 2nd drop down box base on 1st drop down box value</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script language=javascript>
      function updateData(v)
      {
        var value=v.options[v.selectedIndex].value;
        $("#number").empty(); //empty "digit" drop down box
        if (value!="") //Ensure no empty value is submitted to server side
        {
          jQuery.post("getResult.php","type="+value,updateNumber);
        }
      }
      function updateNumber(data)
      {
        var numberData=jQuery.trim(data).split("\n");//split server side response by "\n"
        var number=document.getElementById("number");
        for (i=0;i<numberData.length;i++)
        {
          value=numberData[i].split("-")[0];//get value from server response 
          text=numberData[i].split("-")[1]; //get text from server response 
          option=new Option(text,value);    //for better IE compatibility
          number.options[i]=option;         
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>PHP/Ajax update 2nd drop down box base on 1st drop down box value Demo</h1>
    No number type
    <select id=type name="type" onchange="updateData(this)">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="1">Odd No.</option>
      <option value="0">Even No.</option>
    </select>

    Number
    <select id="number" name="number">
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

php file(file name:getResult.php)

```
    <?php
    $type=htmlspecialchars($_POST["type"]);
    if ($type=="1")
    {
        echo "1-one\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
        echo "3-three\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
        echo "5-five\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
        echo "7-seven\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
    }
    else
    {
        if ($type=="0")
        {   echo "2-two\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
            echo "4-four\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
            echo "6-six\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
            echo "8-eight\n";//Ends-with \n for client side getting data from server side response
        }
    }       
?>
```

Comment: I know the first step is to make the change: <select name='Teams' onchange="updateRoster()"> (for example). The second part is where I'm lost. I'm a complete beginner at this, and I can't find anything that doesn't confuse the hell out of me. Oh well, I'll continue looking.

Comment: "second part" mean "send data to server side " or "send response to client side" or "parse the server side response and update the web page" ?

Comment: "Parse the server side response and update the web page". You completely lost me there.

Comment: Which is your server side response data format?
Can you use jquery?

Comment: What is your server side response? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess I'm not really sure about how to go about that either. There wouldn't really be a server response: once it is given the value, it just refreshes the PHP code, however that's possible.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. The only thing I don't understand is why you are turning the server side response into an array. What is the server returning that has to be parsed?

Comment: Never mind what I just said, I understand. That's the output from the PHP file. Is there a way to refill the select with my PHP code, instead of with Javascript?

Comment: There are no way to refill the select with php code unless your update the whole web page. By the way, that is "AJAX". In fact, you can reformat the php output to xml format, so you don't need to turn the php output to array.